# TypeScript inline type isn't checked

Tags: typescript

There're 2 (at least) ways of declaring a type for a variable in TS, but they seem to be working in a different way. Is it a bug or a feature? Looks like a bug to me.

```js
type T1 = Partial<{ a: string }>

const wrong1: T1 = { a1: 'a' } // this fails which is fine
const correct1: T1 = { a: 'a' } // this doesn't fail which is fine

const wrong2 = <T1>{ a1: 'a' } // this doesn't fail which is wrong
const correct2 = <T1>{ a: 'a' } // this doesn't fail which is fine
```

[link to sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFACgQwE7AJZoDYA8A3lGgFxQDOwG2AdgOZQC%20AfAFDsDGA9ndVADuGPgzgV4SKCTTioAcjTyW3PgN4YMELsDmTkMiouXNOvfsCEjGAJikF4rGXOMrz6npu3A7yB3CdSIyUVIA)

TS even seems to resolve the type correctly, but for some reason doesn't check it.

[image]

Comment: These are not supposed to mean the same thing; `: Type` is a type annotation so you are asking the compiler to check that the value is of this type, `<Type>` is a type assertion so you are *telling* the compiler that the value *is* of this type. But your example is also broken, because all four of these objects *are* assignable to `T1`, because `T1` has no required properties. Only something like `{a: number}` would not be assignable to `T1`. The reason you get an error for `wrong1` is because of excess property checking on object literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your `wrong2` example is that it is a type assertion. There is no runtime support.

[Type Assertion vs. Casting](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#type-assertion-vs-casting)

> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However, type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

[Assertion considered harmful](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#assertion-considered-harmful)

> In many cases assertion will allow you to easily migrate legacy code (and even copy paste other code samples into your codebase). However, you should be careful with your use of assertions. Take our original code as a sample, the compiler will not protect you from forgetting to actually add the properties you promised

So in this case, you are telling the compiler that you "know better" and that the value being assigned to `wrong2` is a different type from what it really is.