# Stricter typing instead of "as" keyword in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Please see the below code:

```js
type Collections = 'Users' | 'Products' | 'Accounts';

// querying a collection
DB.collection('Users' as Collections).doc(docId).get().then(...)

// below I'm misspelling the "Users" as "User" expecting that I'll get an error. But no errors
DB.collection('User' as Collections).doc(docId).get().then(...)
```

How can I enforce the type checking here?

```js
// one way I'm doing that is
const UsersCollectionNameKey: Collections = 'Users';
DB.collection(UsersCollectionNameKey).doc(docId).get().then(...)
```

This works but it is very tedious to pre declare all the collection name variables. I was wondering if we have a typescript keyword like `is` so that it enforces the type checking right there in place? Like

```js
DB.collection('Users' is Collection) // no errors
DB.collection('User' is Collection) // Err: User is not assignable to type Collection
```

Comment: `as` tells the compiler you know better and there is no compile time or run time behavior that enforces the type. If you have `class` instances, you can use `instanceof`. You can also define your own [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) that work at runtime.

Comment: Related: [TypeScript inline type isn't checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195689/typescript-inline-type-isnt-checked/68195841#68195841)

Comment: Removed my last comment.. starting to understand. Can you change the type of `DB.collection` ? Did you write it/make the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Typescript 4.9 (Nov 2022), we now have a [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#satisfies) that does exactly this. You may want to replace the `is` in your question with `satisfies` operator.

An example usage:

```
interface K {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    ccc: string;
}

const k = {
    a: 'asdf',
    b: 324,
    ccc: 'asf'
} satisfies K; // Good

const excessK = {
    a: 'asdf',
    b: 324,
    ccc: 'asf'
    extra: 'adf' // Error: Type '{ a: string; b: number; ccc: string; extra: string; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'K'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extra' does not exist in type 'K'.(1360)
} satisfies K;

const lessK = {} satisfies K; // Error: Type '{}' does not satisfy the expected type 'K'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'K': a, b, ccc

const keyOfK = 'a' satisfies keyof K // Good
```

Answer (score 1):

The `x as Y` syntax is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) which tells TypeScript that you "know" that `x` will always be of type `Y`. This is to allow you to introduce that information in the type system which could not be inferred otherwise.

So with

```
DB.collection('User' as Collections)
```

you're basically telling TypeScript *I **know** `'User'` is a `Collections`, no need to check this* - which is the opposite of what you're trying to achieve.

Instead you need to tell TypeScript that `DB.collection()` expects a `Collections` as parameter, which you do in the definition *of that function*:

```
public collection(name: Collections) {
    // ...
}
```

With this TypeScript will check that the passed parameter is of type `Collections`, i.e. is either `'Users'`, `'Products'` or `'Accounts'`:

```
DB.collection('Users') // no errors
DB.collection('User') // error: Argument of type '"User"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collections'.
```

See this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgZygXigHIBVHCAJxyKgB9iAFCuAEwFc1q7iBBFFOGyzBqAbgBQ4lAgCGOPAFkQAIQAiUAN7ioOqGDYAjBOhRQBSVBmwAKLDIC2EAFyxEyNJlwBKTVAD0flAAPAC0IVDAABboeDERkdDo9mBwFMAywlDGWBDauvkBUAB0JXk6AL7ilVLYOMBQqsoEUDkA7lBKatZeEuKNRebuVljWpORURD6FWHBQlMxUfcoDbpaeo2SUk-6B86kuPBQA5myOmXAAZhHg0EQARJsUdzRxM-VyOOhHdkbQwLNgGQUBwQYCUKCXa6QYjwCweWpEIpAA) for a live example.

If you cannot change the definition of `DB.collection()` you could write a wrapper function as a workaround:

```
function getCollection(name: Collections) {
    return DB.collection(name);
}

getCollection('Users') // no errors
getCollection('User') // error: Argument of type '"User"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collections'.
```

See [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=112&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwRAxsAlnAdgZygXigHIBVHCAJxyKgB9iAFCuAEwFc1q7iBBFFOGyzBqAbgBQ4lAgCGOPAFkQAIQAiUAN7ioOqAHo9UISgAWMrAHMILKADcIWFnApR0AWzDI3D4DIzZtXTA2ACMEdBQoASRUfywACiwZbwAuKBxgCnRLAEpNQN1dAygAOjKCqABfcWqpbAyoVWUCKCwIAHcoJTV4nIlxADNjOKgrYHgYtEwEpNTYRGQp+rytQooIYDYKLEblEujFuMTkiD6ayTGJw+n40nIqIjzirDgoSmYqcUuF2Ju7yke+kM72caR4FAsbG8wigcAGUFAkGIACIyJRkTR0HgXsAoHIcOgLEkwtBgK8wDIKCdgJRYfDEdAiFdfvUiCUgA).

Comment: Fast-forward to Nov 2022, we now have a `satisfies` keyword for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312258/3370568

Answer (score 0):

I can’t double check this as I’m on mobile but instead of doing “Users” as Collection do “Users” as const.

The as const will stop the widening of “Users” to a string so you don’t need to cast it back to the narrower union